# Active Shipping Fedex create international shipment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedex

I'm trying to use the `active_shipping` gem from Shopify to ship and track packages from several carriers.

I'm having trouble with the `create_shipment` method from Fedex carrier. When it's a domestic shipping everything works fine, but when the destination country is different from the origin country, I always get an error message:

`ERROR - 2033: Customs Value is required.` or `ERROR - 3907: Invalid Customs Value`
depending on the service type.

I understand that I have to supply the package content information for the customs declaration, but I didn't find any way to pass it to the method.

I looked in `ActiveShipping::FedEx`, especially the `create_shipment` and the `build_shipment_request` methods, but didn't find anything related to the package content.

Here is how I try to create the shipment:

```
package = ActiveShipping::Package.new(
    weight,
    [width, height, depth],
    {
        units: :metric,
        value: value,
        currency: 'CAD'
    }
)

origin = ActiveShipping::Location.new(
    company: '***',
    address1: '***',
    country: 'CA',
    province: 'QC',
    city: '***',
    postal_code: '***',
    phone: '***',
    address_type: 'commercial'
)

destination = ActiveShipping::Location.new(
    name: shipment.name,
    company: shipment.company,
    address1: shipment.line_1,
    address2: shipment.line_2,
    country: shipment.country,
    province: shipment.state,
    city: shipment.city,
    postal_code: shipment.zip,
    phone: shipment.phone
)

fedex = ActiveShipping::FedEx.new(
    login: '***',
    password: '***',
    key: '***',
    account: '***',
    test: true
)

options = {
    service_type: service_code
}

response = fedex.create_shipment(origin, destination, package, options)
```

Am I missing something or is the `active_shipping` gem simply not compatible with international shipments using Fedex?

With other carriers like Canada Post you can pass an array of `ActiveShipping::PackageItem` but apparently not with Fedex.

I'm using the latest gem version (1.4.2) on Rails 4.2.3

Comment: I know this is stagnant but I'm facing it now, did you by any chance find a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly no, I never found a solution for this. I was going to investigate further and possibly make a PR on the active_shipping repo, but my employer at the time decided to stop using Fedex as a carrier for other reasons, so I stopped looking.

Comment: @Datise did you find any solution ? Even I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: @NitinSatishSalunke No unfortunately, I don't think there is one within the functionality of the current gem. After going over the docs it seems like all fedex needs is an extra xml field. It would be pretty easy to thread a new parameter and add it to their xml building but I haven't had the time to fork/pull request. Hoping to get around to it this week.

Comment: @Datise yes we need to add additional fields in the xml.

Comment: @NitinSatishSalunke I see you made a PR a while ago but I am having trouble reading it, is the COD option to support this problem?

Comment: @Datise COD is just my requirement, you have to just look at the CustomeClearanceDetail part.

Comment: @Datise Btw I feel there is an excellent solution out there instead of wasting time with Fedex's WSDL.

Check this out http://postmen.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link, postmen looks pretty basic. I'm pretty close to finishing this contract so maybe on my next go around.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add the following xml fields just after the

> "ShippingChargesPayment" element
>
> in "build_shipment_request" method

```
       xml.CustomsClearanceDetail do
          xml.DutiesPayment do
            xml.PaymentType('SENDER')
            xml.Payor do
              xml.ResponsibleParty do
                xml.AccountNumber(6xxxxxx61)
                xml.Contact do
                  xml.PersonName('Sender Name')
                  xml.EMailAddress('sender@email.com')
                end
                xml.Address do
                  xml.StreetLines('Steetline 1')
                  xml.StreetLines('Streetline 2')
                  xml.City('Margao')
                  xml.StateOrProvinceCode('GA')
                  xml.PostalCode(403601)
                  xml.CountryCode('IN')
                end
              end
            end
          end

          xml.DocumentContent('NON_DOCUMENTS')

          xml.CustomsValue do
            xml.Currency('INR')
            xml.Amount(100)
          end

          xml.FreightOnValue('CARRIER_RISK')

          xml.CommercialInvoice do
            xml.Comments('Comments from seller.')
            xml.SpecialInstructions('Special Instructions from seller.')
            xml.Purpose('SOLD')
            xml.CustomerReferences do
              xml.CustomerReferenceType('CUSTOMER_REFERENCE')
              xml.Value('Bill D/T Sender')
            end
          end

          xml.Commodities do
            xml.NumberOfPieces(1)
            xml.Description('Pink Toy')
            xml.CountryOfManufacture('IN')
            xml.Weight do
              xml.Units('KG')
              xml.Value(2)
            end
            xml.Quantity(1)
            xml.QuantityUnits('EA')
            xml.UnitPrice do
              xml.Currency('INR')
              xml.Amount(100)
            end
            xml.CustomsValue do
              xml.Currency('INR')
              xml.Amount(100)
            end
          end
        end
```

Comment: hello sir. so how would you add this? What I did was copy paste this on top of `create_shipment` method.

Comment: Or you mean to override the `build_shipment_request` method?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a full example script for FedEx international shipments via the [Python FedEx wrapper](https://github.com/python-fedex-devs/python-fedex) - you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66893792/11555352). It should be fairly easy to translate for use in Ruby.